# Custom combo box recognition in pywinauto

Tags: python, pywinauto

I have below custom combo box.

i tried to select `item` or get `itemcount` from `ComboboxWrapper` from the field, but i guess `pywinauto` is not able to identify the object.

I cannot use `auto_id=CheckboxEdit` as its not unique and we have 6 combobox in the frame.

```
combobox = app.Dialog.child_window(auto_id="AgrementTypeFilter", control_type="ComboBox").wrapper_object()
comboitems = combobox.item_count()
```

Can somebody check on this? Thanx.

```
Custom - ''    (L-1904, T328, R-1750, B374)
['', 'Custom', '0', '1', 'Custom0', 'Custom1']
child_window(auto_id="AgrementTypeFilter", control_type="Custom")
   | 
   | Static - 'Agreement Type'    (L-1900, T330, R-1754, B346)
   | ['Static', 'Agreement TypeStatic', 'Agreement Type']
   | child_window(title="Agreement Type", control_type="Text")
   | 
   | Custom - ''    (L-1900, T350, R-1754, B372)
   | ['2', 'Custom2', 'Agreement TypeCustom']
   | child_window(auto_id="Combo", control_type="Custom")
   |    | 
   |    | ComboBox - ''    (L-1900, T350, R-1754, B372)
   |    | ['ComboBox', '3', 'ComboBoxCCP']
   |    | child_window(auto_id="CheckBoxEdit", control_type="ComboBox")
```

Answer (score 0):

If each custom combo box contains 1 standard combo box, there are few things to resolve it:

1. Find the first combo box (for example) by using `found_index` criterion.
2. Then find descendant combo box unambiguously.

The code should look so:

```
custom_combo = app.Dialog.child_window(auto_id="AgrementTypeFilter", control_type="Custom", found_index=0)
real_combobox = custom_combo.child_window(auto_id="CheckBoxEdit", control_type="ComboBox").wrapper_object()
real_combobox.item_count()
```

---

Another way is using best match names if they are different:

```
combobox = app.Dialog.ComboBoxCCP.wrapper_object()
combobox.item_count()
```

---

Finally you can also enumerate all the descendants of this control type:

```
comboboxes = app.Dialog.descendants(control_type="ComboBox")
target_combobox = [combo for combo in comboboxes if combo.item_count() == 12][0]
```

Method `descendants()` will return filtered list of wrappers. Then it's easy to iterate it and find the target one.

Comment: The first code works but it returns only 1 item count as below. There are 12 items in that combo box.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           ['', 'CCP']

Comment: Also for this code, can we iterate through this code for object "ComboBoxCCP". If so how we can:                                                                            combobox = app.Dialog.ComboBoxCCP.wrapper_object()
combobox.item_count()

Comment: Usually it's possible to add numbers for best match names like this: `ComboBoxCCP1`, `ComboBoxCCP2` etc. But usually it works for control_type only like `ComboBox1`, `ComboBox2` etc. Also `ComboBox0` and `ComboBox1` will match the same first combo box (historically designed).

Comment: Added simple iterating + filter by 12 items in the last piece of code.

Comment: I tried with above simple iterative code, but it returns item out of bound as it has only 1 record.                                                                                              "ItemsSource" .net property retrieves the correct content of the control. How can i use "Itemssource" in the code. for the combo box i can "get_properties" and also use "legacy_properties" but don't find that property.

Comment: What is `"ItemsSource"`? If it's legacy property, you can access it so: `combobox.legacy_properties()["ItemsSource"]` Method `legacy_properties()` returns a dictionary.

Comment: I had tried using legacy_properties but it didn't return all the contents. "Itemssource" is .net property. - Gets or sets a collection used to generate the content of the ItemsControl.

Comment: Hmm... Probably there are some custom properties. We don't support them for now. It's one of the most tricky parts of UI Automation API. And still no ideas how to support them in Python for now.

Comment: Most of my POC on the tool with our .net app is done and it looks pretty good as compared to other open source ones. This is the only pending issue that I currently have and its a important piece of the app. Let me know  when its possible. Thnx.

Comment: There is no ETA. The most important things till nearest summer are Linux AT SPI support & record-replay for UIA with existing set of features. + minor design improvements.